# Did Chewbacca have a formal rank in the Alliance?

Tags: star-wars

We can track Han and Luke's advancement through the ranks in the original trilogy pretty easily.  What about Chewie?  Did he have a formal rank?  If so, what was his rank in each of the movies in the original trilogy?  Or was he just an aide to Han?

Comment: I always wondered the same thing about Teal'c and Daniel Jackson on Stargate SG-1.

Comment: @Omegacron - Daniel was a civilian consultant hired by DoD. Teal'c was an undocumented illegal alien (unless there's in-universe proof that INS issued him papers :)

Comment: @DVK agreed. The same applies here, though, with Chewie basically being Han's civilian partner. In all three cases, though, you could argue that a rank - even an honorary one - would make for a clearer chain of command.

Comment: @Omegacron -  I suspect that the Alliance was a wee bit less bureaucratic than US DoD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there is no mention in any G/Disney Canon or EU/Legends material where Chewbacca has ever received an official rank in the Rebel Alliance or the New Republic.

[Han's biography](http://www.starwars.com/databank/han-solo) on StarWars.com specifically mentions his promotion to General in the Alliance. [Chewbacca's entry](http://www.starwars.com/databank/chewbacca) has no mention of any rank or commission.

This has never been explained, but one of the more common fan-explanations I've seen is that since Chewbacca has sworn a debt to Han, accepting an official position in the Alliance could possibly require him to unwillingly serve away from Han.

Comment: Why not make him a permanent Aide-de-Camp to Han?

Comment: @WadCheber There is literally NO explanation for any of this in any currently existing works. The theory I mentioned isn't mine, just the one that I've seen put forward the most. If I had to hazard a guess, it'd be because it'd just be a title of interest only to the Alliance. Chewie's life debt (and resulting friendship) is the only thing that matters to Chewie/Han.

Comment: I thought the days of Wookie discrimination were behind us...

Comment: @phantom42 I understand what you're saying, I'm just playing with the fan explanation.  You could make Chewie a permanent aide-de-camp to Han, in theory.